# accessing java files in android plugin for Unity

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am writing a plugin using android NDK.right now i have done the following:
  1- wrote simple functions in C++ and made a .so(shared library) of it. code is as follows:

```
#include <jni.h>
 #include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDK_AndroidNDK1SampleActivity"
extern "C" {

static JavaVM   *gJavaVM;
static JNIEnv *env; 
static jobject  gInterfaceObject, gDataObject;
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_gvs_tes_NdkTestActivity_getNumbr(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_gvs_tes_NdkTestActivity_getActivity(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj);};

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_gvs_tes_NdkTestActivity_getNumbr(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj)
{
    jboolean isCopy;
    jstring szLogThis =(jstring) "hellog";
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", szLogThis);
    return szLogThis;

}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_gvs_tes_NdkTestActivity_getActivity(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    jstring logs =(jstring) "Function Started";
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", logs);
    if(env)
    {
        jstring logs =(jstring) "env not null";
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", logs);

    }
    jclass interfaceClass = env->FindClass("com/gvs/tes/testClass");
    if(!interfaceClass)
    {
        jstring logThis =(jstring) "Activity Class Could not be get";
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", logThis);
        return;

    }
    jmethodID altmethod = env->GetMethodID(interfaceClass, "<init>","()V"); 
    jobject objClas = env->NewGlobalRef(env->NewObject(interfaceClass, altmethod)); 


    jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(interfaceClass, "chekClas","(I)V");
    if(!method)
    {
        jstring logThis =(jstring) "Function Could not be get";
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", logThis);
        return;
    }
    jint val = 3;
    env->CallVoidMethod(objClas, method, val);

    logs =(jstring) "Function Ended";
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", logs);

}
```

2- I copied .so file to [myUnityProject]/Assets/Plugins/Android folder.
  3- then i wrote following Script to call function

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class myScript : MonoBehaviour {
//[DllImport ("ndktest")]
//private static extern string Java_com_gvs_tes_NdkTestActivity_getNumbr();
[DllImport ("ndktest")]
private static extern void Java_com_gvs_tes_NdkTestActivity_getActivity();
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    print("hello start");
    //print ("CHECKING return value :       "+Java_com_gvs_tes_NdkTestActivity_getNumbr().ToString());
    Java_com_gvs_tes_NdkTestActivity_getActivity(); // PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
    print("after Function call inside script");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Now My Main problem is 'How to access Java files present in my Android Project'.Kindly point me into right direction if i am doing it stupidly wrong As my Only purpose is to be able to use an SDK(built for android in java) inside my Unity Application.Any Help is greatly appreciated.